# supportedInterfaceOrientations is not working as expected in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uiinterfaceorientation

I want my application to run in Landscape left and right modes. Below is my code. I created an extension for UIViewController and written the below code in that extension files.

```
func shouldAutorotate() -> Bool {
    return true
}

func supportedInterfaceOrientations() -> Int {
    return Int(UIInterfaceOrientationMask.LandscapeRight.rawValue) | Int(UIInterfaceOrientationMask.LandscapeLeft.rawValue)
}
```

But this code is not working as expected.

When I rotate the device upside down in Landscape Left mode, Only charging bar is rotated. Not my view controller. Need help.

Comment: No, that is not your code. Please show your _actual code_. Copy it from your view controller and paste it into Stack Overflow.

Comment: Also, explain _where_ that code is and what the structure of your view controller hierarchy is. Is this code in the _root_ view controller? I'm betting it isn't.

Comment: I created an extension for UIViewController and written that code in the extension file.

Comment: Well, there's your problem. You need to implement this in your root view controller class.

Comment: Actually I just tried making that extension and it _does_ work correctly - the app rotates. So I can't reproduce the issue.

Comment: The same code is not working for me.. Placed this code in my Window rootviewcontroller as well, but no luck..

Comment: can you put the app project on github? Let me download it and see what the problem is.

Comment: Oh, one more thing - did you set the _app_ to do both orientations, in the target General device orientation checkboxes?